# Python3 parse string after keyword

Tags: python, arrays, string, parsing, keyword

I have a variable

```
abc="[<Result id:af2af0>, < Result id:5ebb65>, < Result id:ee0f90>, < Result id:e8ced6>]"

abcd=str(abc)
if isinstance(abc, str):
    print("GOOD")
else:
    print("NOT GOOD")
```

I want to parse this string after keywork="id:" to stock the six value number into array

```
array[0]=af2af0
array[1]=5ebb65
...
```

Comment: This looks like the repr of a queryset. Why did you convert it to a string in the first place?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex :)

```
import re
abc="[<Result id:af2af0>, < Result id:5ebb65>, < Result id:ee0f90>, < Result id:e8ced6>]"
pattern = r'<\s*Result id\:([^>]+)>'

print(re.findall(pattern, abc))
```

Live demo: https://repl.it/repls/AutomaticPlumPixels

You can also use this regex if the keyword can be other words, not just "result":

```
pattern = r'<\s*[^\s]+ id\:([^>]+)>'
```

The `r` in `r''` is to specify regex.